# How do I get an index out of an array, that was created using a foreach loop, and lives inside a text file?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am using a form - to get data -  and looping thru that data to create different arrays in a file called data.txt. I am trying to pull out the index of each array separately. I want to be able to echo (arry1 - value1) in a specific div on the page and echo (arry1 - value2) in a different div on the page etc..

I can get the arrays to print but when i try to call just one specific index out of one specific array I either get the response NULL or the page reads "this page isn't working"

This is what my data.txt file looks like - it is grabbing the data from the form correctly. But if these two groupings are arrays why can i not pull out the info one index at a time?

data.txt

```
{
"let": {
"chef": "tema",
"bio": "temabio",
"image": "temaimage",
"special_name": "pears",
"special_descr": "purple",
"child_name": "bob",
"child_descr": "opie"
},
"cafe": {
"chef": "herb",
"bio": "herbbio",
"image": "herbimage",
"special_name": "apple",
"special_descr": "mike",
"child_name": "Rob Davis",
"child_descr": "blue"
}
}
```

action.php

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.txt"), true); // true for assoc
    $data[$_POST['restaurant']] = array(
        "chef" => $_POST['chef'],
        "bio" => $_POST['bio'],
        "image" => $_POST['image'],
        "special_name" => $_POST['special_name'],
        "special_descr" => $_POST['special_descr'],
        "child_name" => $_POST['child_name'],
        "child_descr" => $_POST['child_descr']
    );
    $newData = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents("data.txt", $newData);
}
?>
```

load.php

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.txt"), true); // true for assoc

foreach($data as $k => $v) {
    echo "<p>" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Restaurant " . $k . "is" . $v . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Chef: " . $v['chef'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "bio: " . $v['bio'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "image: " . $v['image'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Name: " . $v['special_name'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Description: " . $v['special_descr'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Children: " . $v['child_name'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Description: " . $v['child_descr'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "</p>" . PHP_EOL;  
    }
    var_dump($let['chef']);


?>
<?php
$myfile = fopen("data.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread( $myfile,filesize("data.txt"));


fclose($myfile);


?>
```

This is the response:

```
Restaurant letisArray
Chef: tema
bio: temabio
image: temaimage
Name: pears
Description: purple
Children: bob
Description: opie



Restaurant cafeisArray
Chef: herb
bio: herbbio
image: herbimage
Name: apple
Description: mike
Children: Rob Davis
Description: blue


NULL {"let":{"chef":"tema","bio":"temabio","image":"temaimage","special_name":"pears","special_descr":"purple","child_name":"bob","child_descr":"opie"},"cafe":{"chef":"herb","bio":"herbbio","image":"herbimage","special_name":"apple","special_descr":"mike","child_name":"Rob Davis","child_descr":"blue"}}
```

The response reads that "let is Array" so why can i not pull info out of it like I should be able to?

All of these responded with NULL - i tried them inside the function, outside the function, on different pages etc.
I tried using a second foreach loop inside the first loop to pull out the info but I never got it to work.

```
var_dump($let['chef']);
var_dump($let[ "Chef:" "chef"]);
echo($let["bio"]);
echo "Chef: " . $let['chef'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($cafe);

print_r ($myfile);

echo $myfile($let["bio"]);;

echo "bio: " . $let['bio'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Chef: " . $let['chef'] . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;


 var_dump($restaurant['let']);
    var_dump($restaurant["let"]["chef"])
```

If anyone can tell me how to pull out each value by itself that would be great.
I want to be able to print the value of the key "chef" from the array $let and so forth.
 - I have been trying this for 2 days now and I don't know what else to try. Granted i am very new to programming and I do not know 
PHP at all but this seems like it should be very simple. You have an array - you call out the values using the array name and the index key correct?

Comment: Think you may want `echo $data['let']['chef'];` instead of `var_dump($let['chef']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a variable called `$let` anywhere. You have only `$data`, `$k` and `$v`. `$k` has the value `let`, and at that time `$v` has the array of values for that key. If you want to access the data for that key, the array is found at `$data['let']`, so the chef for that is `$data['let']['chef']`.

Comment: Really wish I had asked you guys two days ago!!! Thank you - I was trying to pull things out using the Array name, but knew I was missing a step somewhere. That works. You are brilliant.